# Spring cloud vault not loading properties from vault

Tags: spring-cloud, hashicorp, spring-cloud-vault-config

I am trying to run Java Spring cloud sample connecting to Hashicorp using this sample, it is not pulling values from vault. vault is running, spring cloud is not pulling props from bootstrap.properties at runtime.

https://github.com/luramarchanjo/poc-spring-vault

No errors, it is not pulling values from vault.
For example (From application.properties)
database.username=${DB_USERNAME:[DEFAULT] VAULT WILL REPLACE IT}

It is printing "[DEFAULT] VAULT WILL REPLACE IT", not vaule from vault

Thank you,

Comment: Can you explain anymore than it doesn't load properties? Are there any errors? Are there any logs that might help diagnose a problem? By the way, the versions of spring in that poc are no longer supported.

Comment: No errors, it is not pulling values from vault.
For example (From application.properties)
database.username=${DB_USERNAME:[DEFAULT] VAULT WILL REPLACE IT}

It is printing "[DEFAULT] VAULT WILL REPLACE IT" not vaule from vault

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is the vault sealed. Check if you are able to validate the data from Vault

Check Vault Server Status:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status
```

This command should return JSON indicating whether Vault is sealed or unsealed.

Retrieve Secrets:

```
curl -H "X-Vault-Token: <your-vault-token>" http://<vault_ip>:8200/v1/secret/data/application
```